# Using select distinct on DataTable

Tags: c#, linq

```
public static DataTable GetDataTableFromCsv(string path, bool isFirstRowHeader)
{
    string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";

    string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

    string sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
        @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
             ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
    using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }                   
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\classes.csv";
    var test = GetDataTableFromCsv(dir, true);
    var totalclasses = test.Rows.Count;

    Console.Write("Number of Classes: " + totalclasses);
    Console.WriteLine();
    test.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Studios";
    Console.Write("Col1: " + test.Columns[0].ColumnName);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Col2: " + test.Columns[1].ColumnName);                        
}
```

This is my code so far. The next step is to go through the column named 'studios' and figure out how many values there are that are distinct. How would I go about doing this?

I keep trying but get:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a
>   delegate type linq.

I have the `using System.Linq;` statement in my code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by `Studios` column and then get count for each studio name like:

```
var distinctValues = test.AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int?>("Studios"))
                        .Select(grp => new
                        {
                            Studio = grp.Key,
                            Count = grp.Count(),
                        })
                        .ToList();

foreach (var item in distinctValues)
{

    Console.WriteLine("Studio : {0}, Number: {1}", item.Studio, item.Count);
}
```

If your column type is different from string then replace that in `Field<T>` method.

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZuOH.jpg

I get this exception.

Comment: @user1795631, that means your column is of type `int`. I have updated the answer, hopefully that should work.

Comment: @user1795631, what does `test.Columns["Studios"].GetType()` returns ?

Comment: System.Data.DataColumn

Comment: @hatfieldac, my bad, check `test.Rows[0]["Studios"].GetType()` and tell me what it returns

Comment: @hatfieldac, what is the exact exception message, it shouldn't throw exception. Copy the exception message and paste here

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll Additional information: Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type.

Comment: @hatfieldac, that is an easy fix, replace `int` with `int?` in your statement, I have modified my answer as well